# Finding substring in String in C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am reading lines from a text file for finding their status that has 3 options,can be OUT or Discontinued or Cancelled

I'm doing like this:

```
ifstream inFile("DVD_list.txt");
string line;
char status;
while ( getline (inFile,line) ) {
    std::size_t pos = line.find("Out" || "Discontinued"|| "Cancelled");     
}

return 0;
```

How can I use the find function with or expression?

Comment: find() can only accept one input parameter. Put the list of words in an array, and make another loop inside the while loop to search for each word one at a time.

Comment: you can use `Regular Expressions ` this way is much faster.

Comment: What is the content of each line in the text? Is it only one of those values or a combination?

Comment: Line format starts with Name after that their status which is only one of those

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
if((pos = line.find("Out")) != string::npos)
{
    // handle Out
}
else if((pos = line.find("Discontinued")) != string::npos)
{
    // handle Discontinued
}
else if((pos = line.find("Cancelled")) != string::npos)
{
    // handle Cancelled
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Possibly, you need to make sure that no false positive is detected, such as in "some sample text no Output"!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istringstream is( "I hope it won't rain today" );

auto x = std::find( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
                std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            "rain" );

if ( x != std::istream_iterator<std::string>() ) std::cout << *x << std::endl;
```

Here is a example code.

Answer (score 0):

find() can just match one string constant, you will have to call it three times.
But you might be able to use a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to match these three words and to process a whole line at once.

Comment: This is what i want, but i couldnt find the spesific function, can you tell me ?

Comment: @pflove if you process the line all at once using regular expression, how can you tell if the line contains either of the three values?

Comment: The link provided already contains an example how to use regex in general; the regex you needed would be `"\bOut\b|\bDiscontinued\b|\bCancelled\b"`; notice the \b, they assure that you do not get any false positives as I noted in my answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't see how using `regex` solves the OP's problem. The above regular expression will match if the line contains either of the three values but doesn't tell you which one(i.e some sort of conditional structure to check for a specific value is necessary) or am i missing something?

Comment: To discriminate the three matches, you could put each word into one group and check which group matches.

Comment: Or - if a match is available at all - it would (in this special case!) be sufficient to look at the first character of it. Still, I'm losing the belief in the elegance of this solution I initially even preferred over mine...